# Como inserir dados de um dataframe em um index presente em outro?

Tags: python, dataframe

Eu tenho uma pasta com cerca de 480 arquivos CSV, só que eles não tem um index e eu criei um outro arquivo CSV para ser o index deles (são 119 colunas no index) Quando eu insiro utilizando df.append o arquivo passa a ter 238 colunas, ou seja dobra. Tentei de tudo para inserir esse index como primeira linha antes de ler os arquivos, como eu faço para inserir as linhas de baixo do titulo das colunas deles?

Tentei isso:

```
df1= pd.read_csv('/home/user/TCC/2015/index.csv')
df2= pd.read_csv('/home/user/TCC/2015/data.csv')

df1 = df1.append(df2)
```

Também tentei assim:

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).reindex(df_index.index)
```

Se puderem ajudar, agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Faz o merge, reseta o index e depois faz o novo index:

```
new =  df1.join(df2)
new.reset_index(inplace = True)
new.set_index('index', inplace = True)
```

Apenas para esclarecer, a df.append apensa os bancos de dados. Ou seja, ele soma linhas (soma vertical), mantendo o número de variáveis contante, mas aumentando o número de observações. Por outro lado, quando alguém precisa juntar bancos aumentando o número de variáveis com o número constante de observações, são utilizados comando como df.join e pd.concatenate.

Aqui tem uma apresentação elaborada sobre isso (em inglês): https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: Eu tentei isso mas consegui como resposta:

TypeError: set_index() takes from 2 to 6 positional arguments but 119 were given

Comment: 'index' no comando new.set_index('index', inplace = True) é uma string. Parece que você colocou um objeto com 119 entradas no lugar. Se tiver dúvidas dê uma olhada na documentação para ver como funciona o método: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

Outra coisa, seu problema ficaria mais claro se você mostrasse um exemplo replicável ou disponibilizasse os arquivos

Comment: Eu tentei a função aqui ela cria colunas novas, eu quero inserir os valores de um Dataframe (O qual possui 119 colunas) e quero que outro Dataframe receba esses dados para ser o index. Como no exemplo:
df1 = A B C D
-------------------
df2 = 1 2 3 4
          5 6 7 8
          9 10 11 12
df1 + df2 = dfmerged
dfmerged = A B C D
                   1  2  3 4
                    5 6  7  8
                    9 10 11 12

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver e volto aqui para responder como eu fiz.
Dentro da função: 
pd.read_csv

tem um atributo chamado name, é só colocar o nome que eu quero e as colunas os recebem, exemplo:

df1 = pd.read_csv('caminho/item.csv', name= {"Coluna1", "Coluna2"})

também da pra criar um array com os nomes e passar ele ex:
array ={"coluna1","coluna2"}
df1=pd.read_csv('caminho/item.csv', name=array)